# removing a few whitespaces from string with c

Tags: c, string, visual-studio

First my code printed `yksi  itsekseen  lol` and now it prints `yksiitsekseenlol` and I am trying to print `yksi itsekseen lol`. In the first one there are two and second there's none and I'm trying to have there only one space between the words.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void antikorso(char *dest, const char *src) {
    const char *p = src;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; *p != '\0'; i++, p++)
    {
        if (*p == 'x') {
            dest[i++] = 'k';
            dest[i] = 's';
        }
        else if (*p == 'z') {
            dest[i++] = 't';
            dest[i] = 's';
        }
        else
        {
            dest[i] = *p;
        }
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    char *original = dest;
    char c[10] = "hello";
    while (dest = strstr(dest, c)) {
        memmove(dest, dest + strlen(c), 1 + strlen(dest + strlen(c)));
    }

    char *nat = original;
    char b[20] = "asd";
    while (dest = strstr(original, b)) {
        memmove(dest, dest + strlen(b), 1 + strlen(dest + strlen(b)));
    }
    printf("\n%s", nat);

    char *vit = nat;
    char d[10] = "  ";
    while (dest = strstr(nat, d)) {
        memmove(dest, dest + strlen(d), 1 + strlen(dest + strlen(d)));
    }
    printf("\n%s", vit);
    return vit;
    }



int main(void)
    {

    const char *lol = "hello yxi asd izexeen hello lol";
    char asd[10000];
    antikorso(asd, lol);

    }
```

Comment: This seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Using a debugger you can step through your code, while monitoring variables and their values, to see what's *really* is happening.

Comment: Please fix the closing bracket '}' for the while loops so that your code is a bit more readable.

Comment: And I am confused, your intro seems to indicate that you want to collapse multiple spaces between words to only a single space, yet the starting string in your program (lol) has only a single space between words.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @StephenDocy After removing instances of "hello" and "asd", there may be instances of multiple spaces that need to be collapsed to a single space.

Comment: Yea that is the case what @user3386109 stated

Comment: @michael The problem is that you're using the same code to remove spaces as you are to remove the other strings. So you end up removing both spaces. The `memmove` needs to be changed to only remove 1 space, not both.

Comment: Yea but How do I do that like with this loop I will find the spots where there is doublespace the string d, but the question is how do I configure the memmove to change them to only 1 space and not removing them.. I have tried million ways but can't get it working

Comment: `memmove(dest, dest+1, strlen(dest));` will delete the one character that `dest` points to. You don't need any adjustment to the `strlen` because the output string is one character shorter than the input string.

Comment: yea that definitely works but is there a smart way to delete a whitepace from the start of the string if there is one, because now if the input string starts with "asd" it will leave one whitespace in the start of the string?

Comment: I took the whitespace of from the start already!

Comment: [Please read the formatting help, kiitos.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) Use backticks to delimit verbatim code text.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you almost have it I think, change

```
memmove(dest, dest + strlen(c), 1 + strlen(dest + strlen(c)));
```

to

```
memmove(dest, dest + strlen(c) - 1, 1 + strlen(dest + strlen(c)));
```

I think that will do it.  The code was previously skipping two spaces, so if you back it up one spot, it should include one space in the copy.

That should work for collapsing two spaces down to one space anyway.  You should test what happens if you end up with three spaces in a row.

Comment: You need to adjust the length parameter as well.

Comment: yea this works too there's just one problem when the input string starts with "hello" or "asd" it will leave one whitespace in the start of the string and that shouldn't be there

Comment: yea I did indeed!